# what is the use of script 2>/dev/null in the following script?

Tags: grep, scripting, io-redirection, control-flow

```
$!/bin/sh
if grep "$1" /etc/passwd 2>/dev/null               #Search username at beging of line1
then
         echo "Pattern found - Job Over"
else 
         echo "Pattern not found"

fi
```

Comment: There is an error in the very first line. Did you mean `#!/bin/bash` instead od `$!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Yes it's a mistake the actual line is #!/bin/sh

Answer (score 5):

In bash, 1 means stdout, 2 means stderr(standard error stream)

/dev/null is a virtual device to which you can write anything, and it would consume everything(essentially getting rid of the output).

So, `2> /dev/null` means that, redirect the error output from this command to /dev/null. Essentially meaning, just get rid of the error messages

Answer (score 1):

The intent with `2>/dev/null` is to hide errors produced by `grep` by redirect any diagnostic messages to `/dev/null` (a special device file that discards the data written to it).

The `/etc/passwd` file is generally readable by all users, so I don't quite understand why redirecting the error stream is needed.  However, since the code uses `grep` in an `if` statement, the output that the utility may produce (the lines matching `$1`) may be unwanted, and with `>/dev/null` this output would be discarded. I'm therefore proposing that the `2` in the code is a typo and the author intended to write

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -e "$1" /etc/passwd >/dev/null; then
    echo "Pattern found - Job Over"
else 
    echo "Pattern not found"
fi
```

That is, to `echo` either string, while discarding the actual lines that matched. The `-e` is needed in case the string in `$1` starts with a dash. Also note the corrected `#!`-line.

This could also be done without any redirection:

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -q -e "$1" /etc/passwd; then
    echo "Pattern found - Job Over"
else 
    echo "Pattern not found"
fi
```

The `-q` makes `grep` quit as soon as a match is found, and also makes it quiet (it does not output the matched lines).

---

If this is to `grep` for a *username* in `/etc/passwd`, then using

```
if getent passwd "$1" >/dev/null; then ...; fi
```

would be a better option, as using a plain `grep` may find usernames that contains the string in `$1` as substrings, unless you take care crafting the expression properly (the regular expression is not actually shown in the question).  The `getent passwd` command would exit with a non-zero exit status if the given username was not found in the `passwd` database.

This would also work on systems using a NIS or LDAP database for storing user information, but would *not* work on macOS (no `getent` utility).